# Open password protected csv or excel document on openrefine

Tags: openrefine

Is there a way of importing password-protected CSV and Excel files on open refine?

I have tried to do it in the open refine but the file is not open.

Are there any changes I have customized ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding password protected CSV files: password protection is not a feature of the csv file format, so finding a general support for this is unlikely.

In case of passwort protected Excel files: there are decryption tools available in the libraries used by OpenRefine (see [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/encryption.html)). But they are not used in the code (see [ExcelImporter.java](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/blob/7f9973b74d2b0c5f5aa73083006c06e3ffbc27d8/main/src/com/google/refine/importers/ExcelImporter.java)).

So if this is important to you I would suggest to open a feature request in the [OpenRefine Github Repository](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/issues).

Otherwise remove the password protection in your Excel file by setting an empty password.

Comment: Thanks. it has been very helpful for me